# Excel VBA to create an Outlook Email Rule (broken after most recent update)

Tags: excel, vba, office365

For my work, I have Office 365 ProPlus. During the most recent update on 12/11/2018 detailed with this link: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/monthly-channel-2018#version-1811-december-11

I had some code in an excel spreadsheet that broke after this update. The purpose of the code is to update e-mail rules to move an e-mail to a specific folder that has a specific number in the subject line. The code worked before the update, but now it breaks with a "Memory Overflow" error.

Here is the code, the break occurs at .Enabled = True :

```
' Assign a specific action to take when the criteria is met
Set NewRuleAction = NewRule.Actions.MoveToFolder
With NewRuleAction
    .Folder = oMoveTarget       ' Tell the rule what target folder to use
    .Enabled = True             ' Make the rule active (turn it on - same as placing a checkmark in the box next to the rule name in Outlook.
End With
```

This worked previously, and after extensive debugging I have determined that all the variables are working properly, the problem is that actually enabling the move to the folder no longer executes.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you (as a test) change the destination folder in oMoveTarget?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here.
I found out that

`NewRule.Actions.MoveToFolder.Folder = oMoveTarget`

works but not in the "With" statement you made above.

Second is that

`NewRule.Actions.MoveToFolder.Enabled = True`

gives an error but sets `Enabled` in the structure correctly.
But if the rules are saved, they are incomplete.

So currently only a part solution.

H.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I finally figured out a solution for now. This is only a workaround as I have found that this issue is actually a known issue that was created from a recent Microsoft Update. Its an out of memory issue that relates to this issue shown here.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outlook-error-the-operation-failed-when-selecting-manage-rules-alerts-64b6ff77-98c2-4564-9cbf-25bd8e17fb8b

So here's what I did to fix the issue only temporarily.
Manually create the email rule in outlook. Then in the code, loop through the email rules until you find the rule named what you want. Then edit the condition subject and save it. You can't create a new rule because you can't set .Enabled = True. Here is the code that I have now.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveandCreateRule()
Dim outlookObject As outlook.Application            'We need to define the actual Outlook Application
Dim oNamespace As Namespace                         'Define the Namespace from the Application (should also pull the current session)
Dim Account As outlook.Folder                       'Define the v- account that we will be using to get and send rules
Dim serverRules As outlook.Rules                    'The current rules in the server.
Dim newRule As outlook.Rule                         'The object to store the new rule in (which will be uploaded to the server.
Dim newSrArray() As String                         'The array to store all the SRs (to be put in the rule conditions)
Dim newSrListing As String
Dim i, counter As Integer

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Start initializing Account related variables.
'Start wtih the Application (getting the current Outlook Application)
Set outlookObject = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

'Then get the namespace from the current outlook application (specifically the "MAPI" namespace)
Set oNamespace = outlookObject.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Once the namespace is selected, set the "email" account by finding the one that starts with "email"
For i = 1 To oNamespace.Accounts.Count
    If InStr(1, oNamespace.Accounts(i).DisplayName, "email") = 1 Then
        Set Account = oNamespace.Folders(oNamespace.Accounts(i).DisplayName)
    End If
Next

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Start initializing rule related variables. Find the rule that is named My Cases so we can edit it.
Set serverRules = Account.Store.GetRules

For counter = 1 To serverRules.Count
    If serverRules.Item(counter).Name = "My Cases" Then   ' NewRuleName already exists
        Set newRule = serverRules.Item(counter)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Get the list of SR's separate them into an array of strings, and then add them as subject conditions in the rule.

' Use the Split function to split a long string into elements and enter those into a one dimentional array.  Delimeter defaults to a space ( " ").
newSrListing = buildSRnumberList
newSrArray = Split(newSrListing)

newRule.Conditions.Subject.text = newSrArray
newRule.Conditions.Subject.Enabled = True

' Update the Exchange server with your new rule!
serverRules.Save

MsgBox ("Your email rules were updated and contain the following SR Numbers: " & newSrListing)
End Sub
```